# In rust, how come with modules like rand, you dont include the child module?

Tags: rust, module

In rust you can use a module by typing `use rand::Rng`

when you want to use it you type `let x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0,100);`

if `thread_rng()` is local to the Rng module then how come we dont type `Rng::thread_rng().gen_range(0,100);`

if I try something similar..

```
mod first{
   pub mod second{
      pub fn hello(){println!("hello");}
   }
}

use first::second;
fn main(){
   first::hello();

}
```

then I get an error saying it cant find hello in module first

Comment: You must be confused, `Rng` is not a module, it is a trait, and its totally unrelated to the `thread_rng()` function. Both are at the top level of the `rand` crate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *if thread_rng() is local to the Rng module...*

`Rng` is not a module, it is a trait.

`thread_rng` is a function of the `rand` module.

See the [`rand` docs](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/).